# Can browser plugins draw to a <canvas>?

Tags: canvas, browser-plugin

Some browsers, specifically on Windows, don’t let you overlay content on top of a plugin `<object>`.

Is it technically possible for plugins to draw to a `<canvas>` instead? I suppose this could also differ between browsers and operating systems.